# MongoDB query to retrieve all the content from array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mongodb, helper

I have more arrays but I only want to retrieve content of "PIZZAS"

anybody could tell me which is the correct query?

[image: This is my BSON storaged in mongoDB]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by doing a projection. In the mongo shell it looks like this:

```
db.collection.find({}, { PIZZAS: 1, _id: 0})
```